# Function Output is double but i get an error

Tags: function, simulation, anylogic, modeling

For my following function I get the error message: `This method must return a result of type double`

But my output is a double. Where is my error?

```
if (currentAgent == Halteteil && predecessor == Oberteil) {
    return 40.4;
} else if (currentAgent == Oberteil && predecessor == Ring) {
    return 13.5;
}
```

Haltetil, Oberteil and Ring are my Agents.
The Output is the delaytime for my service Block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility that neither condition is triggered. Java "sees" that and tells you via the error. You must provide a "fallback" as below:

```
if (currentAgent == Halteteil && predecessor == Oberteil) {
    return 40.4;
} else if (currentAgent == Oberteil && predecessor == Ring) {
    return 13.5;
}
return 0.;
```

If you like, you can "catch" that via an error msg or by returning `-infinity` but you have to give Java the ability to always return a double